# Parameter for new Task

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a console app that launched a task like this in the main method:

```
Task t = new Task(Search);
t.Start();
```

I want to change the `Search()` method to accept a parameter but when I do then I try the below code I get an error about converting void to an action:

```
Task t = new Task(Search("keyword"));
t.Start();
```

What is the proper way to be passing a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work :

```
Task t = new Task(() => Search("keyword"));
t.Start();
```

Comment: Bad practice. Use Task.Run.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { 
                                          Search("abc"),     
                                          TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, 
                                          TaskScheduler.Default 
                                          });
```

Comment: Bad practice. Use Task.Run.